# why I can't use tkinter module with batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, tkinter

Batch code:

```
TITLE %~nx0
python "c:\users\aaa\desktop\coding\python\first project with tkinter\buttomtest.py"
pause
```

and python code is:

```
from tkinter import *   
window = Label(text="gg")  
print("tt")
```

and this is what I get:[image]

It shows the cmd prompt window but it doesn't show the window of tkinter

Comment: It seems like you are missing the window.mainloop(). And also packing the ui elements. Please follow this tutorial for more info https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/

Comment: Your Python code exited immediately, probably before the window actually became visible.  You have to call something like `window.mainloop()` (preferably on an actual window, rather than a poorly-named Label) to actually run the GUI.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh thankyou
but can u tell me why i can use my code(without window.mainloop()) in repl.it and it's work?

Comment: oh ic now, sorry

Comment: UWU may be missing a line of code or so though you just can't run python window modules in this DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter is a python module meant **ONLY** for python.
Now I see what you tried to do but learning python may be the way there is an OS module `import OS` which could allow you to run command prompt commands. `os.system("command here")` will allow you to run commands from the system DOS.
Hope this helps and enjoy the community!

Answer (score 1):

You may also run a start command
`start File.py`

`Exit`

Answer (score 0):

way to fix that: window.mainloop()
and there is no need for `import OS`